# Web service to convert location & datetime to UTC

Tags: web-services, geo-location

Does any web service (either free or commercial) exist that converts a location, date and time into UTC?

As background, I'm implementing alarm functionality on an embedded device whose notion of time comes from a combination of NTP and uptime.  I'd rather avoid implementing a local database to handle timezones or daylight saving.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [Time and Date](http://www.timeanddate.com/).

Not only does this present a large number of time formats, there is an API than should be just what you need.

The API calls are rate-limited, based upon your subscription.  There is a free trial available.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the programming language you are utilizing.

C# includes a [UtcNow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx) function to return current UTC time:

```
public static DateTime UtcNow { get; }
```

You can then use local time as a reference for the time difference.

Visual Basic would use the following syntax:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property UtcNow As Date
```